# simulate blazor signalr web socket latency

Tags: google-chrome, browser, websocket, signalr, blazor

I tried in chrome/firefox web tools to select to throttle ajax requests (by selecting slow 3g/ regular 3g etc.), but this doesn't seem to affect the blazor signalr connection which is using web sockets.

is there way to simulate latency for blazor, so it would work locally like on a remote server ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toxiproxy](https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy#cli-example) to create a local TCP proxy. It supports both latency and bandwidth limiting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31470122)